# django custom comment's image field not working

Tags: python, django, image, comments

I'm doing django-contrib-comment's custom comment app to my django app. At long last i achieved my comment app that has image field, and it shows in template of course. But here is the thing, When i'm trying to post comment with **image**, it does not saving image file, and says empty(This field is required). Can anyone help me to figure it out. Here is some code snippets.

models.py

```
class CommentWithPic(Comment):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="comments/%Y/%m/%d/", null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class CommentFormWithPic(CommentForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()

    def get_comment_model(self):
        return CommentWithPic

    def get_comment_create_data(self):
        data = super(CommentFormWithPic, self).get_comment_create_data()
        data['image'] = self.cleaned_data['image']
        return data
```

post_with_comment.html

```
{% render_comment_list for adi %}
    {% get_comment_form for adi as form %}
    <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if field.is_hidden %}
                {{ field }}
            {% else %}
                {% if field.errors %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
                {{ field.label }}
                {{ field }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="hidden" value="{% url 'ad' adi.id %}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="comment"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Is `CommentForm` a `ModelForm`? Have you tried `image = forms.ImageField(required=False)`?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony, yes i've tried required=False if so it's post it but without image file. And, it's CommentForm. As it says in django docs

Comment: So what are you trying to do? You said that if you don't include `required=False` then it will post the review page and complain that the image field is required (which is correct functionality) but if you *do* include `required=False` then it will post the comment without the image (which is also correct functionality)

Comment: All i'm trying to do is post comment with image. But when i tried to do that, seems it's not posting that way

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your form like the following (notice the `enctype` attribute) when dealing with `ImageField

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">\
```

to [bind uploads to a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/):

> Dealing with forms that have FileField and ImageField fields is a little more complicated than a normal form.
>   Firstly, in order to upload files, you’ll need to make sure that your  element correctly defines the enctype as "multipart/form-data"

You also need to make the image optional in the form:

```
class CommentFormWithPic(CommentForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(required=False)

    ...
```

Comment: okay, i just added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and did `requied=False` but still same, it's not posting picture

Comment: actually all the text fields are posted except image field. Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I also faced the same questions as you asked and found out the solution (I used django_comments_xtd library instead)

1. find out which python module is called after user post comment, in my case the url path changed to /comment/post after I submitted form. I trace django_cooments_xtd/urls.py and it called django_comments/urls.py and it called comments.py. you can see it finally call post_comment method in django_comments/views/comments.py
2. just as [link_a](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-uploading-images-in-django/) mentioned, "form = HotelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)", you can see the form object need "request.FILES" as argument but in the post_comment it doesn't use it as arguemnt, so you have to add the arguemnt
   => I modified the code to form = django_comments.get_form()(target, data=data,files=request.FILES)
3. after you modified the code, I think you can get the image object in get_comment_create_data method and you have to save it and you can [link_b](https://dev.to/lb/image-uploads-in-wagtail-forms-39pl) to save it

peace